# Can Netflix Eureka lookup a service based on its metadata?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I know how to add metadata (name/value pairs) for a service to the registry.  Is there any way to do a service lookup based upon these values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually impossible, but it is fairly complicated to do, depending on the size of your application. Please refer to this : https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/458